# Error: “Method getText() must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker.”

Tags: java, android, sqlite, methods, android-edittext

I'm new in android programming. I have made an app where i can fill data and app show this data in the table. But I get an error:

> Method getText() must be called from the UI Thread, currently inferred
>   thread is worker

in the following lines:

> weight.getText() 
>   txtDate.getText()
>   txtTime.getText()

in this code:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String w_value = weight.getText().toString();
        String wdate = txtDate.getText().toString();
        String wtime = txtTime.getText().toString();

        // inserting data
        sqlcon.open();
        sqlcon.insertData(w_value, wdate, wtime);
        BuildTable();
        return null;
    }
```

weight - show number (27.6, 5,0)

txtDate - show date  (20-09-2016, 12-03-1988)

txtTime - show time (15:16, 1:06)

My insertData method:

```
public void insertData(String weight, String date) {

   ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
   cv.put(MyDbHelper.WEIGHT, weight);
   cv.put(MyDbHelper.WEIGHT_DATE, String.valueOf(date));
   cv.put(MyDbHelper.WEIGHT_TIME, new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date()));
   database.insert(MyDbHelper.TABLE_WEIGHT, null, cv);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, I think.  You must call getText from the UI Thread, but you're not -- you're calling it from doInBackground(), which is in a worker thread.  That is not allowed.  Only the UI thread can access UI elements.